# Why ash tree grow upwards and not horizontal?

Tags: trees, tree-care

I have an ash tree and it grows upwards instead of growing leaves, what can I do with it?

[image]

Comment: What a handsome tree!  I believe I see where lower branches were pruned off in the past.  Perhaps it did grow horizontally, and then was pruned back into a loli-pop?

Comment: All forest trees lose lower branches with time due to the shade from other trees. Did the ash tree remain from woods that were cleared? The ash could be 60 years old. If you are asking for help forcing lower limbs, it's possible but they will not be well anchored to the core of the tree, only to the outer layers. Have your nursery plant shorter things nearby to mask your eyesore, if that's the issue.